# JS - How to change image SRC with separate variable?

Tags: javascript, image

How do you change an image path with a separate variable in JavaScript? Here's an example of what I mean:

```
function changeImage() {
    var newName = "image1";
    var imageID = document.getElementById("imageID");
    imageID.src = "images/" + newName + ".png";
}
```

The code I'm actually using is something like this (only the relevant pieces, though):

```
var choices5 = ["Rock", "Scissors", "Lizard", "Paper", "Spock"];

function RPS5() {
    var aiChoiceNumber = Math.floor(aiNumberDecider * 5);
    var aiChoice = choices5[aiChoiceNumber];
    var userchoiceNumber;
    var userChoice = this.value;
    for (var i = 0; i < choices5.length; i++) {
        if (userChoice == choices5[i]) 
            userchoiceNumber = i;
    }
    RPS(userchoiceNumber, aiChoiceNumber, choices5, outcomes5);
    userImage.src = "images/" + userChoice + ".png";
    console.log(userChoice + ", " + aiChoice);
}
```

In case you haven't figured it out yet, I'm making a web-based RPSLS game. The pictures in the directory that I'm trying to reach are there, but they don't change when I click the button to play the game / change my choice.

Thanks to everyone in advance!

Comment: The above code isn't working for you? Because that looks like it should work so long as there really is an image to be found at "`images/image1.png`".

Comment: Yeah, it's not working for me. Again, I've tried everything, but my "newName" is coming from the "value" of a button `var newName = this.value`, but I highly doubt that would cause the problem. If you want, I can post the code I'm currently working with.

Comment: Sure, the more you post, the easier it is to debug.

Comment: Alright, check it out.

Comment: Any console errors that you get?

Comment: Surprisingly, nothing. I also forgot to mention (again, doubt this is a factor in this), but all my pictures are stored in the cloud (OneDrive), along with the JS and HTML files.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166725/discussion-between-aidanm-and-kshetline).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I threw together a quick plunk that picks random images, in case looking at this code might help as a follow-on to our previous discussion: http://plnkr.co/edit/BfFqel0sBnI68vNejUSr?p=preview

```
function init() {
  var images = [
    'https://www.bryanrock.com/application/files/7914/3349/4593/rock.png',
    'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81tAWzf0iKL._SY450_.jpg',
    'https://cdn1.creativememories.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/s/c/scissors1.jpg',
    'http://animals.net/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/Lizard-2-640x425.jpg',
    'http://www.tabletmag.com/wp-content/files_mf/spock62037.jpg'
  ];
  var image = document.getElementById('image');

  setInterval(function() {
    var rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);
    image.src = images[rnd];
    image.onload = function() {
      var nw = image.naturalWidth;
      var nh = image.naturalHeight;

      if (nw > nh) {
        image.width = 300;
        image.height = 300 * nh / nw;
      }
      else {
        image.height = 300;
        image.width = 300 * nw / nh;
      }
    };
  }, 1000);
}
```